# How to get rid of the two lines for empty abstract and keyword sections?

Tags: front-matter

How can I get rid of the two lines resulting from empty abstraction and keyword sections?  Thanks.

[image]

The code is

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt]{elsarticle}

\usepackage[nodots]{numcompress}

\biboptions{sort&compress}

\journal{A Journal}

\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}

  \title{My Title}

  \author[myaddr]{Author 1}
  \author[myaddr]{Author 2}
  \address[myaddr]{An Address}

  %% \begin{abstract}                                                                                                                                          
  %%   Here's an abstract.                                                                                                                                     
  %% \end{abstract}                                                                                                                                            

  %% \begin{keyword}                                                                                                                                           
  %%   keyword1 \sep keyword2 \sep keyword3                                                                                                                    
  %% \end{keyword}                                                                                                                                             

\end{frontmatter}
\section{Introduction}
\label{intro}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you want to submit this article to some publishing company? If yes, the editors would persist on the lines

Comment: no. it is not for publish. It is just for myself, and I think elsevier's template looks good.

Comment: what template also look good?

Comment: Good looking is a rather opinion-based term. It depends on your requirements somehow

Comment: My requirement is simple + not waste space + standard. I don't like Elsevier itself, because it is not free, but I don't know what other latex templates also look good for writing report etc

Comment: I am pretty fine with standard classes as `article` etc.

Comment: Can `article` make the similar thing for author and their addresses as in `elsarticle`?

Comment: `\author` is basically the same, the addresses however do not work this way, unfortunately. If you need them, you have to workarounds or ... stick to `elsarticle` (or another class).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to comment the `numcompress` package out.

The relevant lines are contained in `\pprintMaketitle`, being two `\hrule` statements. For a quick solution, I commented those `\hrule` statements out:

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt]{elsarticle}

\makeatletter
\long\def\pprintMaketitle{\clearpage
  \iflongmktitle\if@twocolumn\let\columnwidth=\textwidth\fi\fi
  \resetTitleCounters
  \def\baselinestretch{1}%
  \printFirstPageNotes
  \begin{center}%
 \thispagestyle{pprintTitle}%
 \def\baselinestretch{1}%
    \Large\@title\par\vskip18pt
    \normalsize\elsauthors\par\vskip10pt
    \footnotesize\itshape\elsaddress\par\vskip36pt
%    \hrule\vskip12pt
    \ifvoid\absbox\else\unvbox\absbox\par\vskip10pt\fi
    \ifvoid\keybox\else\unvbox\keybox\par\vskip10pt\fi
%    \hrule\vskip12pt
    \end{center}%
  \gdef\thefootnote{\arabic{footnote}}%
  }
\makeatother

%\usepackage[nodots]{numcompress}

\biboptions{sort&compress}

\journal{A Journal}

\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}

  \title{My Title}

  \author[myaddr]{Author 1}
  \author[myaddr]{Author 2}
  \address[myaddr]{An Address}

  %% \begin{abstract}                                                                                                                                          
  %%   Here's an abstract.                                                                                                                                     
  %% \end{abstract}                                                                                                                                            

  %% \begin{keyword}                                                                                                                                           
  %%   keyword1 \sep keyword2 \sep keyword3                                                                                                                    
  %% \end{keyword}                                                                                                                                             

\end{frontmatter}
\section{Introduction}
\label{intro}


\end{document}
```

**Edit** A somehow shorter version, with `xpatch` package:

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt]{elsarticle}

\usepackage{xpatch}

% Patching the \hrule\vskip12pt out .. do it twice!!!
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\pprintMaketitle}{%
  \hrule\vskip12pt%
}{}{\typeout{Success}}{}

% Injection the date as a replacement of the 2nd `\hrule` stuff
\xpatchcmd{\pprintMaketitle}{%
  \hrule\vskip12pt%
}{\@date}{\typeout{Success}}{}
\makeatother

%\usepackage[nodots]{numcompress}

\biboptions{sort&compress}

\journal{A Journal}

\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}
\title{Theory on Brontosaurs}

\author[myaddr]{Anne Elk (Misses)}
\author[myaddr]{Arthur Gumby (Brain specialist)}
\address[myaddr]{Ministry of Silly Walks}

  %% \begin{abstract}                                                                                                                                          
  %%   Here's an abstract.                                                                                                                                     
  %% \end{abstract}                                                                                                                                            

  %% \begin{keyword}                                                                                                                                           
  %%   keyword1 \sep keyword2 \sep keyword3                                                                                                                    
  %% \end{keyword}                                                                                                                                             

\end{frontmatter}
\section{Introduction}
\label{intro}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks. where do you find \pprintMaketitle and its definition?

Comment: In `elsarticle.cls`, line 315, at least in the version I've got on my computer

Comment: Is your first method to override its definition?

Comment: The first method `redefines` the `pprintMaketitle` macro effectively by using the whole bunch of code, copied out of the class file, then commenting the two *offending* lines out. The second uses the patch approach, which does not require to copy the code. However, since there are two `\hrule`.... statements there, it must be applied twice (which is strange, to be honest ;-))

Comment: thanks. btw, I try to add the date to the article. Do you know how to do that? I add `\date{May 20, 2015}` before or after \author, but the date doesn't show.

Comment: @Tim: If you look into the first version of my answer, there is no `\@date` command used at all. I think, I can inject it at, as a replacement of the `\hrule` stuff?

Comment: how do you define \date?

Comment: `\@date` is defined in the latex core or in `article.cls` (I don't remember it right now), but `elsarticle.cls` uses `article.cls`. If you use `\date{some stuff}`, this is stored to `\@date`. If `\date` is not specified, `\@date` is defined to be `\today`, i.e. the current date -- see my edit of the second version

Comment: What about for `[final]`? this solution only seems to work for `[preprint]`.

Comment: @LShaver: I never claimed it would work for `final`. The O.P. used `preprint`